# how can i add z-index to pseudo elements

Tags: html, css

How can i make the pseudo element below the ? Therefore, it won't over the text when i hover it.

```
<a href="https://jsfiddle.net/y875wknz/">https://jsfiddle.net/y875wknz/</a>
```

just like this effect in this youtube video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-seV3cls54

i want to use z-index to replace mix-blend-mode. But i don't know why it can't work.

Comment: How can i make the pseudo element below the "a" ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.  There was a REASON why you have a red warning notice when you tried to paste just thie link.

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap the text in a different element and assign it `position:relative` and that would work. Try this code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html> 
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="#"><span></span><em>Button</em></a>
  </body>
</html>

 body{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background:#262626;
      }
       a{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        width:180px;
        height:50px;
        background:#262626;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align:center;
        line-height: 50px;
        color:#ff0000;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size:20px;
        font-family:Verdana ;
        letter-spacing: 4px;
      }
      em{
        font-style: normal;
        position: relative;
        background:#262626;
        height: 50px;
        width: 180px;
        border: 2px solid transparent;
        display: block;
      }
      a::before,
      a::after,
      span::before,
      span::after
      {
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 10px;
        height: 10px;
        background: #ff0;
        z-index: -1;
        transition: 1s;

      }
      a:before
      {
        top:-2px;
        left:-2px;

      }
      a:after
         {
        top:-2px;
        right:-2px;
      }
      span:before
         {
        bottom:-2px;
        left:-2px;
      }
      span:after
         {
        bottom:-2px;
        right:-2px;
      }

      a:hover:before,
      a:hover:after,
      a:hover span:before,
      a:hover span:after
      {
        width: calc( 180px /2);
        height: calc( 50px/ 2);
      }
```

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding.
i want to be this effect, but i don't want to use mix-blend-mode: vue  .
how can i use z-index to replace mix-blend-mode
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-seV3cls54

Comment: i share the youtube link, i want to do that effect.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include some more css rules for em. This would give your desired output. Try it.